# C# сериализация и десериализация в Json объектов, которые "не хотят сериализовываться автоматически"

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Есть объект, для которого сериализация и десериализация не осуществляется автоматически (в моём случае этот объект типа `Matrix<double>` из Emgu CV).
Как его сериализовать и десериализовать?

Я сделал обёртку `MatrixDoubleWrap`над эти объектом, хотелось бы, чтобы она проходила хотя бы вот такой тест:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMatrixDoubleWrapSimplest()
    {
        var src = new MatrixDoubleWrap(1, 1);
        src.A[0, 0] = 0;

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(src);

        var res = serializer.Deserialize<MatrixDoubleWrap>(serializedResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(src.Rows, res.Rows);
        Assert.AreEqual(src.Cols, res.Cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < src.Cols; j++)
                Assert.AreEqual(src.A[i, j], res.A[i, j], 1e-7);
    }
```

`MatrixDoubleWrap` выглядит вот так (из интересного там только конвертация в массив массивов. Можно сериализовать этот массив массивов, но как сделать, чтобы автоматически сериализовывался и десериализовывался именно он?):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

namespace PsLibs
{
    class MatrixDoubleWrap
    {
        public Matrix<double> A;

        public int Rows
        {
            get { return A.Rows; }
        }

        public int Cols
        {
            get { return A.Cols; }
        }

        public MatrixDoubleWrap(int rows, int cols)
        {
            A = new Matrix<double>(rows, cols);
        }

        public double[][] DataArray
        {
            get
            {
                var res = new double[Rows][];
                for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
                {
                    res[i] = new double[Cols];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
                        res[i][j] = A[i, j];
                }
                return res;
            }
            set { A = FromArrayOfArrays(value);}
        }

        private static Matrix<double> FromArrayOfArrays(IList<double[]> src)
        {
            var res = new Matrix<double>(src.Count, src[0].Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < res.Cols; j++)
                    res[i,j] = src[i][j];
            return res;
        }  
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно дописать для того, чтобы это заработало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, вам надо сделать конструктор по умолчанию, чтобы при десериализации объект смог создаться.

Потом, вам надо расставить атрибуты [`[ScriptIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) на тех свойствах, которые вам надо выключить из сериализации. Я так понимаю, что это все кроме `DataArray`.

---

Но я предлагаю пойти другим путем - написать конвертер для `Matrix<double>`:

```
class MatrixConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new [] { typeof(Matrix<double>) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var matrix = (Matrix<double>)obj;
        var res = new double[matrix.Rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Rows; i++)
        {
            res[i] = new double[matrix.Cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.Cols; j++)
                res[i][j] = A[i, j];
        }
        return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data", res } };
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var src = serializer.ConvertToType<double[][]>(dictionary["data"]);

        var res = new Matrix<double>(src.Count, src[0].Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < res.Cols; j++)
                res[i, j] = src[i][j];
        return res;
    }
}
```

Зарегистрировать конвертер типов можно через [`RegisterConverters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters(v=vs.110).aspx) или (для веб-сервисов) через [конфиг](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

PS нет ли способа перейти на Json.NET? Там куда больше возможностей...

Comment: Натыкался уже несколько раз на рекомендации перейти на Json.NET. Возможность вроде есть (если я правильно понял о бесплатности Json.NET). Осталось только понять, действительно ли нужны эти возможности

Answer (score 2):

Для класса JavaScriptSerializer можно определить свои [конвертеры типов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Набросал небольшой пример, здесь есть класс Matrix, для которого определяется кастомный конвертер. Несмотря на отсутствие конструктора по умолчанию, десериализация происходит корректно. Надеюсь, пример натолкнет вас на решение.

```
// пример класса, который нужно сериализовать
public class Matrix
{
    // состояние объекта полностью определяется содержимым этого поля
    // в вашем случае нужно изучить исходники Matrix<T>
    // и определить, какие поля нужно сериализовать (см. далее)
    private readonly double[][] _matrix;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        _matrix = new double[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            _matrix[i] = new double[cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                _matrix[i][j] = rnd.NextDouble() * 100.0;
            }
        }
    }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return _matrix[i][j]; }
    }

    public int Rows { get { return _matrix.Length; } }
    public int Cols { get { return _matrix[0].Length; } }
}

// конвертер типа Matrix из/в словарь
class MatrixConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    // имя поля, которое определяет состояние объекта Matrix
    // их может быть несколько
    const string fieldName = "_matrix";

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary,
        Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        // десереализуем ранее сериализованный массив
        var matrix = (string)dictionary["_matrix"];
        var fieldValue = serializer.Deserialize<double[][]>(matrix);

        var result = new Matrix(fieldValue.Length, fieldValue[0].Length);

        // заменяем значение поля _matrix
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        field.SetValue(result, fieldValue);

        return result;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(
        object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        // через рефлекшен извлекаем содержимое поля _matrix
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        object fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);

        // сериализуем его обычным методом, т.к. это массив и
        // проблем с его сериализацией нет
        return new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { fieldName, serializer.Serialize(fieldValue) }
        };
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(Matrix) }; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var matrix = new Matrix(10, 20);
        var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // Добавляем наш кастомный конвертер
        s.RegisterConverters(new[] { new MatrixConverter() });
        string json = s.Serialize(matrix);

        var newMatrix = s.Deserialize<Matrix>(json);

        // проверка внутреннего содержимого
        Debug.Assert(newMatrix.Rows == matrix.Rows);
        Debug.Assert(newMatrix.Cols == matrix.Cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < newMatrix.Rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < newMatrix.Cols; ++j) {
                Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(newMatrix[i, j] - matrix[i, j]) < 1e-10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все же, я бы не стал использовать рефлексию там, где можно обойтись открытым интерфейсом.

Comment: Спасибо! Но я на тот момент уже успел сделать способом от Pavel Mayorov.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а чем плохо использование рефлексии?

Comment: @PavelMayorov если состояние объекта определяется только данными, которые можно вытащить через публичный интерфейс - то да, без вопросов. Но если там есть какие-нибудь хитрые дополнительные private-поля, то рефлексия понадобится.

Comment: @Schullz рефлексия нарушает инкапсуляцию, медленно работает и выглядит некрасиво

Answer (score 2):

Для полноты, ещё вариант на случай, если вы перейдёте на JSON.NET.

Пусть класс `Matrix` несериализуем по каким-то причинам. Например, это такой класс:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public Matrix(int w, int h)
    {
        storage = new double[w, h];
        W = w; H = h;
    }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return storage[i, j]; }
        set { storage[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public readonly int W, H;
    double[,] storage;
}
```

Для начала, напишем конвертер для «ручной» сериализации. Чтобы не возиться с JSON-атрибутами вручную, положим нужные данные в `JToken`:

```
class MatrixConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Matrix);

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        int w = (int)token["W"];
        int h = (int)token["H"];
        var matrix = new Matrix(w, h);

        JArray payload = (JArray)token["Payload"];
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            JArray column = (JArray)payload[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
                matrix[i, j] = (double)column[i];
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var matrix = (Matrix)value;

        JArray payload = new JArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.H; j++)
        {
            JArray column = new JArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.W; i++)
                column.Add(matrix[i, j]);
            payload.Add(column);
        }

        JObject token = new JObject()
        {
            [ "W" ] = matrix.W,
            [ "H" ] = matrix.H,
            [ "Payload" ] = payload
        };

        token.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Имея такой конвертер, достаточно его применить.

Если класс `Matrix` доступен вам, «оснастите» его атрибутом `JsonConverter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MatrixConverter))]
public class Matrix
{
   ...
```

Если класс `Matrix` лежит в другой библиотеке, и вы не можете добавить атрибут, но он лежит в вашем контейнере, тогда добавьте атрибут к нужному полю контейнера:

```
public class Container
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MatrixConverter))]
    public Matrix Matrix { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь вы можете сериализировать и десериализировать ваш контейнер:

```
var container = new Container()
{
    Matrix = new Matrix(2, 2)
    {
        [0, 0] = 1, [0, 1] = 0,
        [1, 0] = 0, [1, 1] = 1
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container, Formatting.Indented);
var reconstructedContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);
```

Если вы не можете и расставить атрибуты в контейнере (например, их слишком много), добавьте ваш конвертер в список конвертеров при сериализации:

```
var matrixConverter = new MatrixConverter();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container, Formatting.Indented, matrixConverter);
var reconstructedContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json, matrixConverter);
```

Всё!